# How to fix "Use of undeclared type" error in Swift 5.1?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to Swift and iOS development and try to learn by following the official SwiftUI tutorials. I got errors in section 5(https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input). I followed each step meticulously and after I did section 5 step 1, Xcode popped up an error "Use of undeclared type 'UserData'". I tried to ignore and followed through. However, my LandmarkList, LandmarkDetail, SceneDelegate files warned me of the same error. I even checked the completed version of the project that I downloaded from the tutorial page. They looked exactly the same except the parts that I haven't done. Does anyone here have a similar experience as mine or can you kindly offer some suggestions? Thank you!

I'm using Xcode 11 and Swift 5.

This is the UserData class I created under the Models folder.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showFavoritesOnly = false
    @Published var landmarks = landmarkData
}
```

This is the rootview file that keeps prompting errors.

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var userData: UserData  // Use of undeclared type 'UserData'

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List { // Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate
                Toggle(isOn: $userData.showFavoritesOnly){ // Use of unresolved identifier '$userData'
                    Text("Favorites Only")
                }

                ForEach(userData.landmarks) { landmark in
                    if !self.userData.showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite {
                        NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)
                            .environmentObject(self.userData)) {
                            LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
        }
    }
}

struct LandmarkList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ForEach(["iPhone SE", "iPhone XS Max"], id: \.self) { deviceName in
            LandmarkList()
                .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: deviceName))
                .previewDisplayName(deviceName)
        }
        .environmentObject(UserData()) // Use of unresolved identifier 'UserData'
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to clean and close Xcode, then delete Derived Data, then re-open Xcode. I had been constantly having this problem while doing apple tutorials.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! Your magically simple answer saved me from the puzzle I've been struggled with for two days! I should have asked the moment I'm stuck. Again, I want to thank you one more time!

Answer (score 1):

don't need to delete derived data folder or exit Xcode. just close project after tutorial section 5 step 5 then open project, allow it to index build then do step 6. this enables project to rebuild it's cache in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The `.environmentObject(UserData())` should be on the `LandmarkList()` whereas you have it on the `ForEach()`.

```
struct LandmarkList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LandmarkList()
            .environmentObject(UserData())
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Further investigating it doesn't look like that's the actual problem. The Landmarks application works fine for me on Xcode Version 11.2 beta 2 (11B44). It could be that you need to clean Xcode and clear out the Derived Data folder and re-launch Xcode.

Comment: Mine is Version 11.1 (11A1027). Turns out it's the Derived Data folder that's been messing around. I took Evgeniy's advice and now it works!

Comment: @AmirNie I thought that might be the case. Glad you got it resolved.